# Delete local files and database records with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am using ajax to delete files from both database and local. There is no problem on the database side. However I can't delete the correct file from local. I think I can't pass the correct file name... It deletes the local file listed top of the page.

My index.php file:

```
<p><?php echo $file->name; ?></p>

<input type="hidden" name="file-name" value="<?php echo $file->name; ?>">

<button name="delete" id="delete" value="<?php echo $file->id; ?>">
    <span>DELETE</span>
</button>
```

My delete.php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteFile'])) {

    $delFile = $db->execute("DELETE from files WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'");
    $fname = 'upload/'.$_POST['fname'];

    if($delFile){
        unlink($fname);
        echo "File is deleted!";
    }

    else{
        echo "There was a problem!";
    }

}
```

JS file:

```
$('body').delegate('#delete','click',function(){

    var idDelete = $(this).val();
    var nameDelete = $("input[name=file-name]").val();
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

    if(confirm){
        $.ajax({
            url   : "delete.php",
            type  : "POST",
            async : true,
            data  : {
                deleteFile : 1,
                id : idDelete,
                fname : nameDelete,
            },
            success: function()
               {
                parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
               }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: give the full path of the file in  unlink($fname);

Comment: You shouldn't let the client give you the filename to delete. Get the filename from the database before you delete the record.

Comment: I already set the filename with hidden field?

Comment: @Dejavu — That doesn't mean the user can't edit it in the DOM before sending the data back to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is more along the lines of "teach a man to fish" rather than an exact answer because it's hard to tell from your code why that file may or may not be deleted.

First, as other have said your code is extremely dangerous and has the ability for anybody to delete any file on your system - never trust user input.  You might also have a SQL injection vulnerability too.

But, as far as your problem, you are not able to see what is going on because you are ignoring or masking bugs with your code.  To provide some visibility this is what I would do:

```
if($delFile){
    $fname = __DIR__ . '/' . $fname;
    if (unlink($fname)) {
        echo "File is deleted!";
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Unable to delete file with name " . $fname);
    }

}
else{
    throw new Exception("Unable to delete DB record with id " . $_POST['id']);
}
```

Then in your javascript, something to the effect which will output the results of the ajax to the console so you can see what the file path is that is being looked for

```
if(confirm){
    $.ajax({...},
        success: function(){...},
        error: function(jqXHR){console.log(jqXHR.responseText);}

    });
}
```

That probably won't fix your error, but it will allow you to see what is going on, which is likely to be a simple error with the file path.